# Differentiating from 2 different Onsubmits? [React.js]

Tags: reactjs, submit, form-submit

Is there a way to differentiate between different submit buttons? For example, one button could submit a form while one simply logs "Hi!". I tried to create two input with `type="submit"` and giving each a name, however, I did not know my next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons different id's for example

```
<button id="first_button">Click one</button>
<button id="second_button"> Click two</button>
```

Comment: Based on the names, how would I tell react to preform a different action based on which is pressed? Ex. `first_button` logs hi while the second logs bye?